# Render time, event response time of Chrome are too bad

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Render time and event response time of Chrome are too bad.

I've created a sample html which contains about 5,000 - 10,000 rows and here's the result:

With 5,000 rows, it takes FireFox 5s to render and it takes Chrome 11s to render.
With 10,000 rows, it takes FireFox 8s to render and it takes Chrome 3.5 minute to render

I also make a test with following script:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("div.click-test").click(function () {
        $(this).text("clicked");
    });
});
```

With 5,000 rows, in Firefox, the event click responses intermediately, but in Chrome, it responses after about 3s. 
With 10,000 rows, in Chrome, I am not patient to wait the response

Could anybody help me to restructure my html to make Chrome render time better?

PS: You can download my sample here http://www.mediafire.com/?x2h0nsldo90m642. Thanks for any advance

Comment: 1,000 or 10,000 rows for the *long* render?

Comment: what about an example with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or even [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // On every single element, add a click handler.
    $("div.click-test").click(function () {
        $(this).text("clicked");
    });
});
```

You're adding a different event handler on *every single element*. Use event delegation instead. It allows you to have *one* event handler to take care of all your elements.

```
$('body').on('click', '.click-test', function() {
    $(this).text('clicked');
});
```

Also, avoid slow selectors such as `div.click-test`. `.click-test` is way faster.

Comment: Thank you. Your experience is very useful. However the response time is 0.5s(Firefox)-3s(Chrome). Is this problem of Chrome?

Comment: @user929794 if for the same code, one is slower, it is a problem of Chrome :) I'm surprised this is so slow with 5k rows though.